# SCSS Duplicate Rule Elimination

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently starting up a front-end build somebody else made. The project is not letting me do a commit until the linter check succeeds. It tells me that there is a duplicate rule here

```
@media (min-width:0) and (max-width: 575.98px){
    background: #fff;
    right: 5%;
    right: calc(5% - 2px);
}
```

Not knowing much about SCSS, I am not sure whether these are truly duplicate (they appear to be). I am also not sure as to how one should eliminate the redundancy to allow the linter to proceed. My hunch is to delete the first line `right: 5%;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS is not more than an easier way to write CSS (it compiles to CSS in the end) and the linting error you get, is because you define the `right` property twice, while it should only be defined once as a property for clarity. That's why linter rules are in place to keep your CSS/SCSS consistent.

The only problem here is, what was the value to use: was it `5%` or `calc(5% - 2px)`? Either way, the last one defined will be picked up.

```
@media (min-width:0) and (max-width: 575.98px){
    background: #fff;
    right: 5%;
    right: calc(5% - 2px); // « will be picked up
}
```

Example for last properties used:

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS(SCSS) accepts *last value of same property*.
So you should leave only one of your **right** property.

Moreover you should delete **(min-width: 0)** in media, because it is **(min-width: 0)** BY DEFAULT.